# How to use Unscaled Time while instantiating prefabs in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am instantiating some prefabs of particle effects. I want moving the particles when my game is in pause mode. But I am not getting the way to use Time.unscaledDeltaTime!

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target) 
{

    if(target.gameObject.tag == "tag_spike") 
    {
    Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

 }
```

Comment: never use "unscaled time" for any reason; indeed you rarely use the "Time" calls in unity for any reason.  if you want a timer, use **Invoke**. It's that simple.  Your question does not even show what you are trying to do, but it would be as simple as `Invoke("DestroyTheSparklers", 2f)` to get rid of them after two seconds.

Comment: I think the question was aiming for having particles still be animated while `Time.timeScale == 0`. Have a look at this (the lower answers), that might help you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/445843/how-to-emit-particle-or-un-pause-particle-when-tim.html

Comment: Just as Gunnar B. said. But if you'll need something more in the future (pause everything except a cinematic big boom or such), you'll have to implement a cutscene (see docs), or if that's not good enough, write your own pause logic and leave Time.timeScale alone.